# Joining dynamic databases from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a master database that has a table called **companies** that has a column named **db_name** that contains the name of the database for that company.

There are multiple databases with identical structures for these companies.

In each identical database there is a table called action_log with a structure like this:

```
log_id | user_id | action_id
```

I would like to somehow run a query to get the activity for all the users in these databases together. Is there a way to do this similar to the example below?

```
select c.company_id, c.company_name, a.log_id, a.user_id, a.action_id
from master_db.dbo.companies c
    inner join [c.db_name].dbo.action_log a
```

Comment: for particular company? No where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code the following algorithm.

1 - Create a cursor to grab the company database name from master_db.dbo.companies.

2 - For each database name

A - Create a dynamic sql for 'USE [DB]' where DB is the company database name.

B - Add a semicolon to run multiple statements.  Append the query above.

C - Execute the query.  Insert the results into a table.

3 - Return the results table.

What you are trying to do with, **[c.db_name].dbo.action_log**, syntax will not work since at compile time, it can not resolve the item in the brackets [].

You can use my VLFs procedure as a starting point.

http://craftydba.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/usp-monitor-vlfs.sql_.txt

J